# HAPI FHIR java @create interaction does not return any response

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have implemented Appointment booking where @Create interaction is used to create an appointment. Now I want to return MethodOutcome for booked appointment as the reponse of @create method.

```
MethodOutcome oMethodOutcome = new MethodOutcome();
oMethodOutcome.setId(new IdDt("Appointment", "3746", "1"));
```

However, the hapi framework is not returning any reponse.
How should the ideal response look like and why is HAPI not returning it ? I just get empty response for now and the status code if HTTP 201.

HAPI Create example : http://hapifhir.io/doc_rest_operations.html

FHIR Standard : https://www.hl7.org/fhir/overview-dev.html#1.8.1.6

Btw, I am using postmant client to test this webservice